# What's the least costly way to take video in the dark?

Tags: night, video

I want to take some video of a friend with a motor disorder while he is sleeping. We are doing this to help get information about what happens while he sleeps.

I have a tripod and set up my iPad to video tape. But as soon as I turned off the light, the iPad could record nothing. I thought the iPad camera mode might have some way to brighten the image so that I could record, but nothing happened.

What is the least costly way to film my friend in the dark?

Comment: This is probably off topic here, but briefly: Use a dim red light source for minimal disruption of biological sleep processes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this [app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/night-mode-camera-photo-video/id635717655?mt=8).
I have not tried that app but it may work (although it is optimized for iPhones it may work for iPad please check that once)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest buying a baby camera with built-in night vision, like the [DCS-825L](http://us.dlink.com/products/baby-monitor/wi-fi-baby-camera/). Costs around 180$, also has built-in motion detection and you can can control it from your iPad.